# При вводе телефона Please enter your phone (or bot token) телеграмм ждет пароль

Tags: python

Здрасте!
Суть проблемы следующая: программа PуCharm в момент запуска кода выводит сообщение "Please enter your phone (or bot token)", ввожу номер телефона аккаунта в формате +38***...., затем PуCharm просит ввести код подтверждения, поступает сообщение в телеграмм с кодом подтверждения и я его ввожу. Больше ничего не происходит, а через 5 минут телеграмм отправляет еще одно сообщение с текстом типа о незавершенной попытке входа!, то есть, код подтверждения введен правильно, а пароль не введен, хотя PуCharm не просил ввод пароля от аккаунта! Поиск по гуглу ничего не дал  Вдруг кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну загляни в свой код, что там вообще делается. pycharm тут совсем ни при чем.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос снят! Суть в двухфакторной авторизации от телеги, т.е. в коде нужно было дописать password="123456789" в client.start () где 123456789 пароль двухфакторной авторизации!

Comment: Куда конкретно нужно вводить password="123456789" в client.start ()?

Answer (score 0):

Отключите двухфакторную аутентификацию